# How to convert key datatype of a map in dart? For example the from Map<String, dynamic> to Map <DateTime, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a stream of data which look like this

[image]

and then I want to convert the string datatype of the time, to the DateTime datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Map class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/Map-class.html), you have a [map()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/Map/map.html) method that you can use it to convert your map to another map.

simple example:

```
final newMap = oldMap.map<DateTime, dynamic>(
    (key, value) {
      //create your date here
      final date = DateTime();
      return MapEntry(date, value);
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` method to achieve that like the following:

```
final data = {
    '2020-04-26 12:55:31.852306': 'data',
    '2020-04-26 00:55:31.852306': 'data'
  };

final convertedData = data.map((key, value) => MapEntry(DateTime.parse(key), value));
```